# Find Git reference from Puppetfile

Tags: puppet

In our complex Puppet environment we use a big Puppetfile, which always lists for each module its Git URL (`:git`) and reference (`:ref`):

```
(...)

mod 'foobar',
  :git => 'ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7777/pup/puppet-foobar.git',
  :ref => 'puppet-foobar-3.14'

(...)
```

Module versions are updated all the time, so the value of `:ref` changes often.

When we run the Puppet agent via command line, is there a way to know which `:ref` is applied on that particular run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Puppet master includes a version number in every catalog generated which you can customise via the `config_version` environment setting.

This is logged and displayed when the agent runs and applies the catalog:

```
Info: Applying configuration version '1488468780'
```

(showing the default, the Unix/epoch timestamp of the compilation)

This can be any piece of data including a timestamp, an SCM revision number (e.g. git SHA) or something more human readable.

If you have a lot of modules, it's probably best to use the revision of the Puppetfile itself, assuming it's tracked in source control. If using git, you could probably use `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the current revision.

Configure the `config_version` parameter in your environment.conf ([docs](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/config_file_environment.html), e.g. `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/environment.conf`) to point to a script:

```
config_version = '/usr/bin/git --git-dir $confdir/environments/$environment/.git rev-parse HEAD'
```

(from [R10k + Directory Environments - Gary Larizza](http://garylarizza.com/blog/2014/08/31/r10k-plus-directory-environments/))

R10k also has a good git-based script that you may find useful: [config_version.sh](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-r10k/blob/master/files/config_version.sh), which includes the latest commit message and SHA.